# How to deal with initial js increasing in NextJS

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I'm building an application using NextJs and using the library NextUI.
But everytime I use a component that is client based the initial JS increases.

I'm currently at `276kb` and NextJS marks it as red, when I remove the NextUI components the initial JS is `87.4kb` and all is green and fine.

In this case this is just one library, but more will probably be added as I go on.

How do you deal with the initial JS size?

How to deal with 3rd-party libraries?

Is it common that the initial JS becomes "to big" as the application grows?

[image]

[image]

Edit:

I have tried with LazyLoading as suggested below, but it gives me this error:

```
Argument of type '() => Promise<{ default: typeof import("C:/Workspace/Testing/nxt/node_modules/.pnpm/registry.npmjs.org+@nextui-org+button@2.0.26_@nextui-org+system@2.0.15_@nextui-org+theme@2.1._p7a2rgx64a7per3dxo4qpijkaq/node_modules/@nextui-org/button/dist/index"); ... 5 more ...; useButtonGroupContext: () => ContextType; }>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DynamicOptions<{}> | Loader<{}>'.
  Type '() => Promise<{ default: typeof import("C:/Workspace/Testing/nxt/node_modules/.pnpm/registry.npmjs.org+@nextui-org+button@2.0.26_@nextui-org+system@2.0.15_@nextui-org+theme@2.1._p7a2rgx64a7per3dxo4qpijkaq/node_modules/@nextui-org/button/dist/index"); ... 5 more ...; useButtonGroupContext: () => ContextType; }>' is not assignable to type '() => LoaderComponent<{}>'.
    Type 'Promise<{ default: typeof import("C:/Workspace/Testing/nxt/node_modules/.pnpm/registry.npmjs.org+@nextui-org+button@2.0.26_@nextui-org+system@2.0.15_@nextui-org+theme@2.1._p7a2rgx64a7per3dxo4qpijkaq/node_modules/@nextui-org/button/dist/index"); ... 5 more ...; useButtonGroupContext: () => ContextType; }>' is not assignable to type 'LoaderComponent<{}>'.
      Type '{ default: typeof import("C:/Workspace/Testing/nxt/node_modules/.pnpm/registry.npmjs.org+@nextui-org+button@2.0.26_@nextui-org+system@2.0.15_@nextui-org+theme@2.1._p7a2rgx64a7per3dxo4qpijkaq/node_modules/@nextui-org/button/dist/index"); ... 5 more ...; useButtonGroupContext: () => ContextType; }' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType<{}> | ComponentModule<{}>'.
        Type '{ default: typeof import("C:/Workspace/Testing/nxt/node_modules/.pnpm/registry.npmjs.org+@nextui-org+button@2.0.26_@nextui-org+system@2.0.15_@nextui-org+theme@2.1._p7a2rgx64a7per3dxo4qpijkaq/node_modules/@nextui-org/button/dist/index"); ... 5 more ...; useButtonGroupContext: () => ContextType; }' is not assignable to type 'ComponentModule<{}>'.
          Types of property 'default' are incompatible.
            Type 'typeof import("C:/Workspace/Testing/nxt/node_modules/.pnpm/registry.npmjs.org+@nextui-org+button@2.0.26_@nextui-org+system@2.0.15_@nextui-org+theme@2.1._p7a2rgx64a7per3dxo4qpijkaq/node_modules/@nextui-org/button/dist/index")' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType<{}>'.
```

[image]

I was a bit fast there, it do work you just need to specify it better:

```
const Button = dynamic(() => import('@nextui-org/button').then((x) => x.Button));
```

But I thought NextJS managed this in the background, splitting external libraries to their own package .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use **lazy loading** in Nextjs.

The code below explains 3 strategies in Nextjs, read the comment above each section.

```
'use client'
 
import { useState } from 'react'
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
 
// Client Components:
const ComponentA = dynamic(() => import('../components/A'))
const ComponentB = dynamic(() => import('../components/B'))
const ComponentC = dynamic(() => import('../components/C'), { ssr: false })
 
export default function ClientComponentExample() {
  const [showMore, setShowMore] = useState(false)
 
  return (
    <div>
      {/* Load immediately, but in a separate client bundle */}
      <ComponentA />
 
      {/* Load on demand, only when/if the condition is met */}
      {showMore && <ComponentB />}
      <button onClick={() => setShowMore(!showMore)}>Toggle</button>
 
      {/* Load only on the client side */}
      <ComponentC />
    </div>
  )
}
```

**note:** If the function or component that we want to import from the desired file is not the default export, we can use the following way:

```
const ComponentD = dynamic(() => import('../components/D').then((mod) => mod.D))
```

I hope it will be effective.

Comment: Thx for the suggestion, I forgot to mention this, will updated my question.
I tried the dynamic but it gives me error on the NextUI component. See my edit above

Comment: hmm I was a bit to fast there.. it works but I need to use then: const Button = dynamic(() => import('@nextui-org/button').then((x) => x.Button));

Comment: @J4v4Scr1pt so Is it work?

Comment: Yes with the use of "then". If you could add an example with then to your code for others to see, then I can mark it as Solved :)

Comment: @J4v4Scr1pt okay, sure 